# Как работают синглтоны Java?

Tags: java, android, static

Читая книгу "Программирование под Android" Брайна Харди, я столкнулся со следующим кодом. Существует класс синглтон:

```
public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;
    private Context mAppContext;

    public ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    private CrimeLab (Context appContext){
        mAppContext = appContext;
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<Crime>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public static CrimeLab get(Context c){
        if (sCrimeLab == null){

            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab (c.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sCrimeLab;
    }
}
```

Существует ещё один класс, в котором обращаются к методу get и getCrimes класса CrimeLab:

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
    }
}
```

Меня интересует эта строка кода `mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();`. Как мы обращаемся к CrimeLab, если мы не создали экземпляр класса CrimeLab, а статической является лишь переменная sCrimeLab в CrimeLab? Могу предположить, что приставка s не учитывается, или я сильно не понимаю принцип синглтонов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` в данном случае является обозначением статической переменной, но название никак не влияет на её суть, оно может быть любым.

Метод `get`, также является статическим.

В коде написано, что если `sCrimeLab` является `null`, то необходимо создать экземпляр класса в ином случае вернётся существующий экземпляр.

По хорошему можно разделить строку `mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();` на

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
mCrimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
```

Comment: Принцип работа синглетного класса я понял, но мне всё ещё непонятна та строка кода. Получается, что мы обращаемся к статическому методу get, он создаёт и возвращает экземпляр класса CrimeLab, затем через "." мы обращаемся к его методу getCrimes?

Comment: @WinterFox добавил в ответ